# Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to send the `Button` `View` to another activity, eg.

```
Button bttn=(Button )findViewById(R.id.bttn)
startActivity(new Intent(this,Account.class))
```

by using bundles we can send values from 1 Activity to another activity,same way how i can send view to another activity..

Comment: what for? it sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't send views between activities. Instead, create a separate button in the second activity and send only the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple..

Create a method like this in original activity:

ex:

```
public Button getButton(){
    return bttn;
}
```

and declare buttonview as `static`.

By declaring it `static` you can access this view in another activity.

Call this method from another activity and get it and use it.

Comment: Wow... that's even worse. It's insane... I wish you hadn't written that.